# c# linq list with varying where conditions

Tags: c#, linq, list, csv

```
private void getOrders()
{
    try
    {
        //headerFileReader is assigned with a CSV file (not shown here).
        while (!headerFileReader.EndOfStream)
        {
           headerRow = headerFileReader.ReadLine();
           getOrderItems(headerRow.Substring(0,8))
        }
    }
}

private void getOrderItems(string ordNum)
{
    // lines is an array assigned with a CSV file...not shown here.
    var sorted = lines.Skip(1).Select(line => 
        new 
        {
            SortKey = (line.Split(delimiter)[1]),
            Line = line
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.SortKey)
        .Where(x => x.SortKey == ordNum);

    //Note ordNum is different every time when it is passed.
    foreach (var orderItems in sorted) {
        //Process each line here.
    }
}
```

Above is my code. What I am doing is for every order number from headerFile, I process the detailLines. I would like to only search for those lines specific to the order nr. The above logic works fine but it reads with where clause for every order number which simply is not required as well as delays the process.

I basically want to have getOrderItems something like below but I can't get as the *sorted* can't be passed but I think it should be possible??

```
private void getOrderItems(string ordNum)
{
    // I would like to have sorted uploaded with data elsewhere and I pass it this function and reference it by other means but I am not able to get it.

    var newSorted = sorted.Where(x => x.SortKey == docNum);
    foreach (var orderItems in newSorted) {
        //Process each line here.
    }
}
```

Please suggest.

**UPDATE :**  Thanks for the responses & improvements but my main question is I don't want to create the list every time (like I have shown in my code). What I want is to create the list first time and then only search within the list for a particular value (here docNum as shown).  Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean *the sorted can't be passed*?

Comment: Why not using `Where` first and then `OrderBy` ? will be much more efficient.

Comment: `.OrderBy(x => x.SortKey)` does not make any sense if all your items have the same `SortKey` (i.e. equal to `ordNum`).

Comment: Since you're asking for suggestions, I would also suggest that you don't put `get` in the method names for functions that return `void`. And purely as a style suggestion method names are CamelCased in C# (are you coming from Java?).

Comment: I agree with @Ian; a better name for `getOrderItems` would be `ProcessOrderItems`, or it should be modify to actually *return* order items for a certain `ordNum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a good idea to preprocess your input lines and build a dictionary, where each distinct sort key maps to a list of lines. Building the dictionary is `O(n)`, and after that you get constant time `O(1)` lookups:

```
// these are your unprocessed file lines
private string[] lines;

// this dictionary will map each `string` key to a `List<string>`
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> groupedLines;

// this is the method where you are loading your files (you didn't include it)
void PreprocessInputData()
{
     // you already have this part somewhere
     lines = LoadLinesFromCsv(); 

     // after loading, group the lines by `line.Split(delimiter)[1]`
     groupedLines = lines
        .Skip(1)
        .GroupBy(line => line.Split(delimiter)[1])
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
}

private void ProcessOrders()
{
    while (!headerFileReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var headerRow = headerFileReader.ReadLine();
        List<string> itemsToProcess = null;
        if (groupedLines.TryGetValue(headerRow, out itemsToProcess))
        {
            // if you are here, then
            // itemsToProcess contains all lines where
            // (line.Split(delimiter)[1]) == headerRow
        }
        else
        {
             // no such key in the dictionary
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have updated my post.. Please let me know your feedback.

Comment: @Anirudh: I believe this answer should be what you need; `groupedLines` dictionary should be created only once, when you load the `lines` from your `csv` file. Whenever you call `TryGetValue` on this instance, you will get a list of all lines which match that key (and this happens very quickly, since it's just a jump to a hashtable bucket). To make it clearer, I can make `groupedLines` a field.

Answer (score 1):

The following will get your way and also be more efficient.

```
var sorted = lines.Skip(1)
    .Where(line => (line.Split(delimiter)[1] == ordNum))
    .Select(
        line => 
            new 
            {
                SortKey = (line.Split(delimiter)[1]),
                Line = line
            }
    )
    .OrderBy(x => x.SortKey);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have updated my post.. Please let me know your feedback.